# Find the a pair of tuple with the closest sum to a given number

Tags: python, list

I try to define a function that takes in a list & an int and gives back a tuple of the list element that sums up to the int.

I try to loop through all elements in the `alternateSumList` to give all possible tuples. However, I got only 1 possibility with a wrong order.

```
def closestPairsAlt(List, value):
    calculateDifferenceList = [value - x for x in List]
    alternateSumList = []
    for i in range(len(calculateDifferenceList)):
        if calculateDifferenceList[i]>=0:
            alternateSumList.append([calculateDifferenceList[i]+List[i], i, List[i]])
    for x in range(len(alternateSumList)):
        val1 = alternateSumList[x][2]
        searchValue = value - val1
        if searchValue in List:
            val2 = searchValue
        else:
            pass

    return(val1, val2)

List = [1,3,5,7,9]
value = 8
```

Comment: * to give all possible tuples* - only 2-item tuples are needed? how about `(1,3,4), (3,5)` from `[1,3,5,4,9]` ?

Comment: I'm only looking for 2-item tuples. Yes you are right I want to have `(3,5)` as a result too but cant get it with my code.

Comment: When I ran your code, I got `(7, 1)` which is equally close to the desired sum as what you want. What is the tie-breaking criteria?

Comment: I guess the OP expects a positionally closest items

Comment: (3,5) and (1,7) are two possibilities that result in 8. Which one are you looking for? Both?

Comment: Yes both and in that exact order.

Comment: That sums up to the int or exactly to the int?

Answer (score 1):

Short one-liner with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) feature:

```
from itertools import combinations

def closest_pair_sum(lst, value):
    return list(t for t in combinations(lst, r=2) if sum(t) == value)

lst = [1,3,5,7,9]
value = 8
print(closest_pair_sum(lst, value))
```

The output:

```
[(1, 7), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import itertools

def f(items, val):
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(items)), 2):
        if items[i] + items[j] == val:
            print(items[i], items[j])

list = [1,2,5,7,9]
f(list, 8)
(1, 7)
(3, 5)
```

Comment: OP specified that the function should return a list of tuples, not print them.